# XAML/UWP Trouble with User Control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using Visual Studio 22 with an UWP Project.

I have tried to create a user Control 'Logo' in my project with an custom dependency Property 'Label'.

But when I try to use this Control on my MainPage.xaml
I get this error message:
`The XAML Binary Format (XBF) generator reported syntax error '0x09ca'`

XAML of Custom Control:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.UI.Images.Logo"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    >

    <Grid>
        <Image
            x:Name="ImageLogo"

            />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind of user Control:

```
namespace MyApp.UI.Images
{
    public sealed partial class Logo : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Label",
            typeof(string),
        typeof(Logo),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
            );


        public string Label
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
            }
        }
        
        public Logo()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page xmlns:my="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"  
    x:Class="MyApp.Pages.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:UI.Images="using:MyApp.UI.Images"
    >
    <Grid>
.....
        <UI.Images:Logo/>
....
   </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem:

The namespace `xmlns:UI.Images` in the MainPage.xaml was it.

```
`<Page xmlns:my="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"  
x:Class="MyApp.Pages.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:UI.Images="using:MyApp.UI.Images"
>
<Grid>
    <UI.Images:Logo/>
</Grid>
```

After renaming it to `xmlns:Logo` it worked